# Why doesn't == and != defaults to object.Equals for ValueTypes?

Tags: .net, struct, equality

For classes, == and != uses object.ReferenceEquals. But for structs, == and != is not defined.

```
struct S { }
S s1 = new S();
s1 is ValueType; // true
S s2 = new S();
object.Equals(s1, s2); // true
s1 == s2; // operator '==' cannot be applied.
```

The default behavior for ValueType equals is reflecting over all fields and checking equality, right..? So why isn't == and != defined to just use object.Equals for structs?

Then I took a look at System.Int32 in Mono to see what they did.. Int32 derives from `IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable, IComparable<Int32>, IEquatable<Int32>`, but it does not implement == and !=... But still, == and != can be used on integers as expected.

Is there some compiler magic happening on one of these interfaces or with the built-in valuetypes? Or am I missing something crucial here?

*Edit:* Btw, could the reason == isn't implemented on structs be for performance reasons? Using reflection to iterate over all the fields might be a bit slow...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison for [`System.Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) are defined in the C# norm in *14.9.1 Integer comparison operators* and are mapped directly to the IL opcodes like [`OpCode.Ceq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ceq.aspx) for equality in the C# compiler so they aren't defined as standard operators on the `System.Int32` type directly.

So yes compiler magic it is.

Answer (score 2):

ValueTypes should be boxed in order to be used as (how you call them) types aka objets.
Boxing is a performance penalty, yes.